# Should a Game include Multi-Monitor Support?

Tags: resolution

I'm coding a 2D platformer in SDL2 and c++ and was wondering if there's an expectation for videogame's to support Multi-Monitor setups and if so, if it applies to 2D platformers.

As a bonus question too: Does the expectation of being able to change a game's resolution apply to 2D platformers? Thanks.

Comment: It depends what exactly you see as multi monitor support. I expect at least an option to choose on which screen the game should be run or an easy way of switching the game between screens. Many games crash or don't size properly when I move them to the other monitor. One game was running fine when I moved it to the other screen but only with 30FPS instead of 60 and the game speed was also half of the usual speed. Not nice. ;) Switching primary monitors often messes up desktop icon layouts.